# If the client and server use the same certificate file for a secure connection over SSL?

Tags: ssl, client-server, ssl-certificate, boost-asio

I am tring to figure out how a secure connection between client and server is established. I tried the SSL example provided by boost::asio library. My question is about the certifacte used by client and server. To be specific, I generated a private key(mykey.pem). Then I used this private key to generate a self-signed certificate(mycert.pem) and I used these files as follow:

### Server side:

1)context_.use_certificate_chain_file("mycert.pem", error);

context_.use_private_key_file("mykey.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem, error);

context_.use_tmp_dh_file("dHParam.pem",error);

### Client side:

2)ctx.load_verify_file("mycert.pem",error);

With this code the handshake is done perfectly. My question is that how come both the server and client use the same certificate ("mycert.pem") in commands 1 and 2? With this approach a client can pretend to be a server easily.right? Do you think that I missed something here?

Answer (score 3):

The certificate is public information.

It's the private key that allows the entity to prove its identity. The client is guaranteed by the SSL/TLS handshake that only the party with the private key matching the public key in the server certificate can be at the other end with the suitable master secret, so as to be able to decipher the communication. The problem it addresses is whether or not the remote party is indeed the one to which the certificate was issued. (This is similar to checking that the picture on the photo ID matches the person in front of you.)

Configuration of the certificate (and not the private key) on the client side is there to tell it which certificates you are willing to trust. The problem it addresses is whether or not to trust what the certificate say (in particular what it says about the identity of the server). This is normally done using a PKI, so as to build trust via 3rd parties (the CAs). (This is similar to checking that the photo ID itself is genuine, and that you can trust what it says.)

What you've done by trusting this specific server certificate is bypass the use of CAs to make an exception and indicate you were willing to trust this particular certificate to be genuine. (This is fine for a handful of certificates, but using a CA allows your trust structure to be more manageable and add other features, such as the ability to revoke certificates.)